# How to fix string cannot convert to boolean

Tags: string, boolean

a string cannot be converted to boolean

this is a condition for a while loop

```
boolean yes = "true", no = "false";
```

I expect the output should be if the user input "yes" the while loop will repeat and if "no" the loop will break

Comment: Please post the code you've written that you describe.

Comment: You're trying to assign a `String` to a boolean variable. You need to compare the user input to the `String` and then assign that to the boolean

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you're using, as well as showing us a [mre] (please read that web page).

Answer (score 0):

You can create one method that will take string and return boolean value.

```
func isBoolean(String: yourString) -> boolean { 
    if yourString == "yes" 
       return true
    else 
       return false
}
```